# Loading a shared C/C++ library depending on libtorch immediately before importing torch

Tags: c++, ctypes, libtorch

I have a shared library named liblodepng.dylib.
depending on libtorch. It is mixed C and C++ and depends on libtorch. The following code crashes python:

```
import ctypes
lib_projn = ctypes.CDLL( "<my private root directory>/build/liblodepng.dylib")
import torch
```

Changing the order like this gives me an error message:

```
>>> import torch
>>> lib_projn = ctypes.CDLL(
...     "<my private root directory>/build/liblodepng.dylib"
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(<my private root directory>/build/liblodepng.dylib, 6): Symbol not found: __ZNK3c1010TensorImpl20is_contiguous_customENS_12MemoryFormatE
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.dylib
 in /usr/local/opt/libtorch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib
```

Comment: You need to create a [mre]: minimal version of the code for shared object, how exactly it is build and which version of libtorch and py torch is used.

Comment: So why load it after `import torch`? It seems that's loading the wrong *libtorch.dylib* (or dependency).